# Changing nest package manager

Tags: npm, nestjs

I created a new nestjs project using **nest-cli** that uses **npm** package manager. Is there any way to change package manager to **yarn** or I have to make a new nest project?

Comment: when we run `npx @nestjs/cli new` it let you choose the package manager. I didn't understood your question

Comment: or, I got it. NestJS's CLI isn't bound to the package manager. You can swtich to yarn just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to change it after the fact you can delete the `node_modules` directory and the `package-lock.json` and run `yarn` to install packages via yarn. If you are creating a new project you can use `nest new <project-name> -p yarn` to auto-use yarn or follow the wizard and choose yarn. Other than that there are no direct ties to the package manager, so use what you like. I personally like pnpm so I use that for all of my nest projects